# Upper bound on arc length by chord length

Tags: geometry, circles

Consider an arc and the corresponding chord of a circle, as in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html. Then is it possible to bound the arc length by the length of the corresponding chord? Specifically, can we have the following inequality,
$$
s\leq Ca
$$
for some universal constant $C>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unit circle, we have $a = 2\sin \left({\frac {s}{2}}\right)$, and so
$$
\frac s a = \frac{s}{2\sin(s/2)} \le \frac \pi 2
$$
for $s \in [0,\pi]$.